# Solving for Conditional Density

Tags: probability

The problem asks: "Conditionally, given $X=x$ let $Y\epsilon U(0,x)$ and let $X$ have density $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^{2}}$ for $x \geq 1$. Find density of $Y$"

In my head this seems easy, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong. We know that $f _{Y|X=x}(y)= \frac{f_{X}(x,y)}{f_{x}(X)}$  In the problem we're given $f_X(x)$. My problem is calculating the joint density. Is it as easy as saying $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = (1/x)\cdot (1/x^2)$? I got $\frac{1}{x}$ for the density of $Y$ just from knowing it is $U(0,x)$. In this case the conditional density of $Y$ would be $\frac{\frac{1}{x^{3}}}{\frac{1}{x^{2}}}$ which also turns out to be $\frac{1}{x}$

I'm assuming I did something wrong. Is that how you would calculate the joint density and approach this problem?

Comment: Please improve the readability of your question by using the $\LaTeX$ support.

Answer (score 1):

If $0<y\leq1$ then: $$F_{Y}\left(y\right)=\int_{1}^{\infty}P\left(Y\leq y\mid X=x\right)x^{-2}dx=\int_{1}^{\infty}yx^{-1}.x^{-2}dx=\frac{1}{2}y$$

If $y>1$ then:$$F_{Y}\left(y\right)=\int_{1}^{\infty}P\left(Y\leq y\mid X=x\right)x^{-2}dx=\int_{1}^{y}1.x^{-2}dx+\int_{y}^{\infty}yx^{-1}.x^{-2}dx=1-\frac12y^{-1}$$

The PDF can be found by differentiating the CDF.

Answer (score 0):

The pdf of $Y$ is clearly supported on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and:
$$f_Y(t) = \int_{t}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x}\cdot  f_X(x)\,dx $$
so $f_Y(t)$ equals $\frac{1}{2}$ for $t\in\left(0,1\right]$ and $\frac{1}{2t^2}$ for $t\in[1,+\infty)$.